# Are two lines parallel if there are two perpendiculars to the second line between them?

Tags: geometry

I came across a question like this:

In a triangle ABC, there are 2 perpendiculars to any line 'l' passing through A from B and C namely BM and CN. D is the midpoint of BC. MD and ND are joined. We have to prove that ND = MD.

To tackle this one, I started like this:

- Since BM and CN are 2 perpendiculars to the same line 'l', corresponding angles are equal which implies that BM || CN.

So now, is MN || BC or do we need another condition? If so, can it be applied to this problem without making a construction?

If MN || BC, we have a parallelogram BCNM where one angle is 90°. Therefore, BCNM is a rectangle.This implies that BC = MN and BM = CN. Therefore by proving ΔDNC and ΔBMC are congruent by the SAS congruence criterion, we will get ND = MD.

Can this problem be solved without making a construction, or is it possible to solve this one only by making a construction?

Comment: $MN$ can't be assumed to be parallel to $BC$ since both $M$ and $N$ are on $l$, which is any line passing through $A$...

Comment: So is it possible to solve this problem in some other way without making any construction?

Comment: What do you call "midpoint" of the triangle?

Comment: You say: "D is the midpoint of the triangle"... What do you mean by "midpoint"? Is it the centroid? or the midpoint of $BC$? Or something else?

Comment: Made the edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the projection $D'$ of $D$ on $l$.

Then since $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$, its perpendicular projection is the midpoint of $MN$.

All points on the perpendicular to $l$ coming from $D'$ are at equal distance from $M$ and $N$.

In particular $DM=DN$.